# customers don't recive Woocommerce completed orders

Tags: wordpress, email, woocommerce

I have a store with downloadable digital products attached to them.
My customers recently don’t receive confirmation emails with the downloadable links in emails.
Please tell me how I  can solve the issue

I have checked in Woocommerce settings- emails – completed orders…and everything was fine
also I have checked system report, nothing was wrong

Comment: This sounds like not a code problem, but possibly an SMTP problem. You should troubleshoot whether or not your server is actually sending emails - I'd say try asking your webhost for assistance on this one, at least to help narrow the problem down.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Thank you @tobybot , I am using inferno hosting, I will try to contact them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so the main reason because of the coinbase plugin, I reinstalled it and change  order status to completed in plugin code and customers already recieve their products